# invaild function while using express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

invaild function while using express.js
in my app.js where express is installed some of the functions are not working

```html
app.get("/",(req,res)=>{

  const options = {
    "method": "GET",
    "hostname": "alexnormand-dino-ipsum.p.rapidapi.com",
    "port": null,
    "path": "/?paragraphs=1&words=1&format=json",
    "headers": {
      "x-rapidapi-key": "dcc30b2b2fmshac3b7e241a8fc6cp1061bdjsn8937e7e638cb",
      "x-rapidapi-host": "alexnormand-dino-ipsum.p.rapidapi.com",
      "useQueryString": true
    }
  };

  
  https.get(options, function (response) {  
    response.on("data",function(data){
      const dinoData =  JSON.parse(data);
      const b = dinoData.replace('[', '')
      console.log(b);
    })
  })


  res.render("main");
  })
```

*emphasized text*
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRc9P.png)

Answer (score 1):

`dinoData.replace('[', '')` is incorect because of dinoData is not a string but object

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are doing a replace on an object (here - `dinoData.replace('[', '')`), you would either have to iterate over the keys like below and check the values, or also check the keys etc. Or you could maybe remove the data you dont want before parsing the string to an object, but I would recommend the former and not the latter as you may corrupt the JSON.

```
const myJson = JSON.parse('*valid-json-goes-here*')
for (const key in myJson) {
  // Might not be what you want, just an example
  myJson[key] = myJson[key].replace('[', '')
}
```